# Aggregate Rating Rich Snippet doesn't show up in Google SDTT

Tags: schema.org, microdata, google-rich-snippets

I am trying to get stars rating in Google's search but I can't get it working.

If I test the following code in the [data testing tool](https://developers.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/) it says that the code if working fine, but if I use it in a webpage and test it with the URL it doesn't show up for some reason.

```html
<div itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
       <span itemprop="name">CompanyName</span>
       <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating">
         Door klanten beoordeeld met <span itemprop="ratingValue">4.2</span>/5 gebaseerd op <span itemprop="reviewCount">35</span> reviews
    </div>
```

Is there a specific place where I have to put this code?

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Google doesn’t guarantee displaying a Rich Snippet, and there can be [various reasons](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/89650/17633) not getting a Rich Snippet even if the markup is correct. -- How long did you wait after implementing it before checking in Google Search?

Comment: It's now 12 hours since I've placed it in a webpage, but if I test the url in the testing tool (linked above in the starting post) it doesn't show anything but the Website.

The title of this question is edited wrong.. I didn't try it to show up in google's search, but in the testing tool it does work if i paste the code directly into it but it doesn't if I paste the code into a webpage, upload it and then test the URL in the testing tool.

Comment: Ah, I see. I edited the title again (If it’s still not correct, please [edit] it). -- Do you have an example link for a page that contains this markup, but where the tool doesn’t recognize it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breadcrumb with Schema.org not showing in Google Rich Snippets testing tool](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13088284/breadcrumb-with-schema-org-not-showing-in-google-rich-snippets-testing-tool)